# windows update keeps reinstalling buggy nvidia driver

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

Windows 10 Pro on Lenovo W520 with Quadro 1000M.

Connecting external UHD monitor at 30Hz works with 341.81 driver, however, windows update keeps installing newer drivers, that crashes immedeately
when connecting the external monitor at that resolution.

Contacting Microsoft support yielded the solution of rolling back the driver update by hand, all the time. I have no idea if it makes sense to contact NVIDIA.

I tried update-disabling powershell tricks from other answers, they seemed to stick for a while, but after the anniversary update the problem is back.

Is there a sane solution that does not involve buying new computer or reinstalling driver by hand after each reboot?

Answer (score 2):

You could check this, if applicable for your problem -> How to temporarily prevent a driver update from reinstalling in Windows 10

-> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930

Comment: They have updated "Roll Back Driver" in the Windows 1607. Let's see if supplying "crashes on connecting external UHD" as a reason will keep the driver from reinstalling.

Comment: Doing only the "Roll Back Driver" does not stop Windows from reinstalling it.

Comment: Running `wushowhide.diagcab` does not list NVIDIA driver as update that can be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Device manager -> Right click the device -> Update driver -> Browse my computer for driver software -> Let me pick from a list of variable drivers on my computer

In the list you can choose which driver windows will use. Hopefully the list contains more than the buggy one.